# Extended WPF toolkit DoubleUpDown IsEnabled trigger changing background not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, isenabled

I am using an extended WPF control, which is DoubleUpDown.
For this control a have defined a style and within it a trigger for IsEnabled property.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type extToolkit:DoubleUpDown}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

For IsEnabled property I am using a binding from the ViewModel.

The problem is that when the control IsEnabled property is False the background is not all filled with pink, the pink color appears only between Up and Down buttons (See image).

How can I resolv this in order to fill all the control with the new pink color?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: i've briefly skimmed the DoubleUpDown code and this line in NumericUpDown\Themes\Generic.xaml may be your problem: `<local:WatermarkTextBox x:Name="TextBox" Background="Transparent"`

Comment: Setting a different style (the same way it is defined above) for WatermarkTextBox seems to work. Now, when the DoubleUpDown is disabled, the color is changed. But now appears another problem: The value is not displayed anymore and also I cannot introduce any value in the DoubleUpDown control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the latest source code.  Make sure to compile the project located under the Main folder.